in AWS how can I use AppRunner and have no running instances till there is work that need to be done
I have an application in AWS that uses AppRunner using the example provided by AWS. i was wondering if there is a way to not pay for the compute running till a task is needed.
I followed this one: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apprunner/latest/dg/getting-started.html but didn't find an answer

it looks like from the console you can't set it to less than 1 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apprunner/latest/dg/manage-autoscaling.html

When there's no work to do, in AppRunner you don't pay for CPU cycles, only for the memory.
See https://nathanpeck.com/build-your-application-easily-efficiently-serverless-containers/
